# Python Scrapy on Windows missing server command

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have installed scrapy and scrapyd using the pip installer on my Windows 8.1 machine. I have created a project with a scrapy.cfg in place. However, I am missing all the server commands necessary to run scrapyd.

This my C:\Python27\Scripts folder. Below is when I am in the root folder of my project and run the [scrapy] command followed by the [scrapyd] command

[image]
[image]

[image]

**Where are the rest of my scrapy/scrapyd commands, specifically the ones below?**

```
Available commands:
deploy        Deploy project in Scrapyd target
runserver     Deprecated command. Use 'server' command instead
server        Start Scrapyd server for this project
```

Comment: Try to install all your `scrapy` stuff in a virtual environment. You can find more information of virtualenv [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).